# Izpack post install script not working: error 2

Tags: unix, izpack

I'm trying to create an installer for a suite of command-line tools using packjacket and izpack. I have added some post-install scripts under executable and flagged them for running after the install. However, when I run the installer on unix systems (Mac OS X and Linux), I get the following error message:

Cannot run program "/.sh": error = 2, no such file or directory.

What might be causing this? I can post the xml, but it's fairly long so I'll do it when someone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

There is most probably a path issue in your `install.xml`. Here are some things you can try:

- Make sure you are not using wildcards or regular expressions in your `targetfile` fields (i.e. you are not trying to mark `<executable>` all the files in a directory with a single command). If you added your files to the pack with`<fileset>`, mark each of them `<exectuable>` one by one.
- Make sure that you use `$INSTALL_PATH` in your `<file>` and `<executable>` tags instead of explicit relative paths (such as starting with `./`).